# Stripe payment error opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

we have installed stripe payment module in opencart its give error message on checkout page please check following error:-
"Notice: Error: Could not load model /home/imarkclients/public_html/prime/catalog/model/payment/stripe_payments.php!"

Please let us know how we can do it

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because `/home/imarkclients/public_html/prime/catalog/model/payment/stripe_payments.php` is not found. Make sure you have it at the right place.

Answer (score 0):

> "stripe_payments.php"

model file is missing on the path. Please check properly in your folder path.